# Problem using 2 motors

Tags: motor, joystick

I would like both the motors to spin the attached wheels forward when I push the joystick forward and vice versa. When the joystick is still, the motors should stop spinning. At the moment, when I push the joystick on x-axis and my `x` variable increases both motors spin, but when I push it in the opposite direction and `x` decreases, only motor A spins. Additionaly when I connect the arduino to the power (usb cable to my pc), motor B spins for approx 1 second and then stops.

This is the circuit I have (sorry for a lack of schematic, let's hope this wonderful drawing is enough):
[image: Text]

The code:

```
int MotorAA = 7;
int MotorAB = 8;

int MotorBA = 11;
int MotorBB = 12;

int x = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  
  pinMode(MotorAA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorAB, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(MotorBA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MotorBB, OUTPUT);


  digitalWrite(MotorAA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorAB, LOW);

  digitalWrite(MotorBA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(MotorBB, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  x = analogRead(A0);
  Move();
  Serial.println(x);
}

void Move() {
  if (x == 0){
    return;
  }
  
  if (x > 520)
  {
    digitalWrite(MotorAA, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MotorAB, LOW);

    digitalWrite(MotorBA, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(MotorBB, LOW);
  }
  else if (x < 480)
  {
    digitalWrite(MotorAA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(MotorAB, HIGH);
    
    digitalWrite(MotorBA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(MotorBB, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(MotorAA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(MotorAB, LOW);

    digitalWrite(MotorBA, LOW);
    digitalWrite(MotorBB, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: How much current are the motor pulling?  Powering DC motors off the Arduino board is usually a recipe for smoke.  The 5V pin is not there to power your project.  You need to power the motors separately.

Comment: @Delta_G Thank you for answering. I've connected the motor driver module to the usb charger with 5V and still the same. When I connected the meter between the motor driver and the motor it showed ~0,12A.

Comment: @jsotola Good point, I'll update the post. I would like the motors to spin the attached wheels forward when I push the joystick forward and vice versa. When the joystick is still, the motors should stop spinning.

Comment: isolate the area of failure ... swap the A lines with the B lines ... does the problem stay with the motor? ... does it move ? .... switch the motors ... does the problem follow the motor? .... that kind of testing will allow you to determine where the failure is occuring

Comment: @jsotola Strangely enough, when I left only the ground and power connected to the driver, motor B acts the same. I thought that without powering the motor `a` and `b` pins on the driver, it shouldn't move.

Comment: the motor will turn only if IA and IB are different ... you can remove the Arduino .... plug the L9110s into the breadboard .... connect all four inputs to ground ... connect the motors .... now connecting any one of the four inputs to V+ should run one of the motors .... test all of the four inputs, one at a time

Comment: @jsotola I did what you said and I think there's a problem with the pin B-IA, which when connected to power doesn't spin the engine. I've looked at the module and saw that there's some solder missing(I think?) on R5 [image](https://i.imgur.com/eZj9ciK.jpg) could this be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino can definitely not power that many motors. The Arduino's max output current is 0.1A and you might be drawing around 0.5A. Use an external battery like a LiPo battery for the motor controller.

NOTE: Please watch out! Drawing that many amps from Arduino can kill it! So please use the LiPo or normal batteries!